# How to replace +27 with a Zero (0) on a South African cell number using a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace the +27 prefix on a South African Cell Phone number using a regular expression, please help guys.

**Example:**

```js
let number = "+27712345678";
number = number.replace(/[+27]/g, "0");
console.log(number);
```

output is: 000010345608

All I want is to just replace the +27 with a Zero (0) and leave everything as it is.

Thanks you guys in advance.

Comment: `.replace(/\+27/, "0");`, assuming there are no weird spaces or other phone number specific details, which i don't know about.

Comment: Your problem is that `[+27]` matches any characters in the set `+`, `2` and `7`, **not** the sequence `+27`. That is why your output is the input with *all* of those characters replaced with `0`. @ASDFGerte comment is what you want.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks a lot, this is indeed what I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `^` ( start of string anchor )

```
 ^\+27
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `\+` - Matches `+`
- `27` - Matches number `27`

---

```js
const replacePrefix = str => str.replace(/^\+27/, '0');

console.log(replacePrefix("+27712345678"))
```

***Note:-*** `[+27]` character class means match any  of the characters specified inside character class, so here it means match either of `+ or 2 or 7` one time since we don't have any quantifier after character class